# SQL SUM result always show double data

Tags: sql, oracle

I using TOAD for my ORACLE query, now I have question, why the result of query always show 2 whereas I have grouped my column.

To make a clear, here it's my code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
M.MODEL_NO,
P.FORM_NO,
P.MODEL_NO,
P.DATE_ADDED,
Q.FORM_NO,
Q.STATUS_QTY,
SUM(Q.QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY M.MODEL_NO ORDER BY M.MODEL_NO
RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) QTY  

FROM
SEIAPPS_MODEL M, SEIAPPS_PRODUCTION_STATUS P, SEIAPPS_QTY Q  

WHERE
P.FORM_NO = Q.FORM_NO AND P.MODEL_NO = M.MODEL_NO AND M.MODEL_NO = '17' AND P.DATE_ADDED 
BETWEEN '2013-08%' AND '2013-10' AND Q.STATUS_QTY = 'OK'
```

For sum Quantity is successfull, but my question, why the result always show double with the same data?
The logic is, if same Model No, then it will SUM it although have a different date added.

Comment: Can you show some sample output, because I can't make head or tail of what you're asking.

Comment: You haven't grouped your column; you're using an analytic `sum`, not an aggregate. Presumably there are at least two rows in the source data that match your conditions? You're asking for the total sum for the `m.model_no`, for every related row in `p` and `q`. You couldn't use a `group by` here and still show the different `p.date_added` values as that column would have to be included in the `group by` too. And if you have two dates, the `distinct` isn't going to collapse those to a single result. So, you need to figure out what you actually want, I think...

Comment: Also, what datatype is `date_added`? The `P.DATE_ADDED BETWEEN '2013-08%' AND '2013-10'` condition doesn't make any sense for a date column, and I have no idea what the `%` wildcard character is doing in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you meant to order by P.DATE_ADDED in the windowing clause.